# Stripe - how to list active and trialing subscriptions together

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using NodeJs with Stripe. I want to retrieve all active and trialing subscriptions of one customer in a nice way. So far I was only able to retrieve subscriptions separately.

```
const activeSubscriptionsObject = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
    customer: customerId,
    status: 'active'
  });



const trialingSubscriptionsObject = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
    customer: customerId,
    status: 'trialing'
  });
```

What should I do to get a subscription object that contains both trialing and active subscriptions?

Comment: Have you tried passing the values as an array like so `status: ['active', 'trialing']` or comma separated values like so `status: 'active,trialing'`?  I don't know if it's gonna work though, they don't mention it in the docs unfortunately.

Comment: @Molda I tried to use `status: ['active', 'trialing']`. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve two explicit status (and not others) like you've asked. The way to do this is either:

1. As you've done, retrieve `active` and `trialing` separately then merge the results; or,
2. Request the list with `status=all` to get everything ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-status)), then filter the results yourself.

Like so:

```
const allSubs = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
  customer: customerId,
  status: 'all'
});
const statuses = ['active', 'trialing'];
const trialAndActiveSubs = allSubs.data.filter(sub => statuses.includes(sub.status));
```

Comment: Your allSubs is a complex object in the form: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list. It is not that easy to filter through this object

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I missed the `data` layer. Fixed above to use `allSubs.data.filter(...)`